# LuaLaTeX does not print italic greek letters (\setmainfont{EB Garamond})

Tags: luatex, greek, italic, ebgaramond

Since a few days LuaLaTex does not print any italic greek letters into the PDF when using the font EB Garamond as the main font.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{wut}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond} 
\begin{document}
\textit{Ο καθένας μπορεί να θυμώσει, είναι εύκολο. Αλλά να θυμώσεις με τον σωστό άνθρωπο, στο σωστό βαθμό, για τον σωστό λόγο, τη σωστή στιγμή και με τον σωστό τρόπο, αυτό δεν είναι καθόλου εύκολο.}

\textit{Jeder kann wütend werden, das ist einfach. Aber wütend auf den Richtigen zu sein, im richtigen Maß, zur richtigen Zeit, zum richtigen Zweck und auf die richtige Art, das ist schwer.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No problem for me with an up-to-date TeX Live 2023. What does your log say?

Comment: Nothing wrong in the log.
lualatex --version
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023)
Development id: 7581
I do have an older TeX Live 2023 which works well, but shows the same Development id??

Comment: It could be a font problem. You use `fontspec` to load the font, which also loads fonts installed in your system. Maybe, you have another version of EB Garamond installed that lacks Greek letters? Make sure that you use the OpenType font that comes with TeX Live 2023.

Comment: To be sure that it is not a problem with the document class: Where can one find `wut.cls`?

Comment: you cross posted to tl list where you did finally post the log, As @JasperHabicht guessed you are not using the texlive versions of the font

Comment: Yes, I did not recognize that there was a second installation of the fonts on this instance in /usr/share/fonts ... Which did not work properly. Sorry. After removing them everything works fine.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.